# How to write a SQL Query that returns columns that contains Yes and No?

Tags: mysql

I want to write a SQL Query that returns all people's names with a column called Fav_Blue that contains Yes or No depending on whether the person has Blue as a favourite colour or not.

There are 2 tables:

- People (ID, Name)
- Favourite_Colour (person_ID, Colour)

In Favourite_Colour table, there are the following rows:

- (1, Blue)
- (1, Red)
- (1, Black)
- (2, Green)
- (3, Blue)

I tried the following query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN FC.Colour = "Blue" THEN  "Yes"
    ELSE "No"
    END AS Fav_Blue, P.Name
    FROM People P, Favourite_Colour FC
    WHERE P.ID = FC.person_ID
```

The problem in the output is that I have 2 rows with Mark showing Yes and No:

- (Mark, Yes)
- (Mark, No)
- (Sara, No)
- (Eric, Yes)

because the person with ID 1 has Blue and other colours as favourites.

I only want to show the (Mark, Yes) row without the other one.

What do I have to change in my query to achieve this?

Comment: You will need to do a group by on the name or people id so you only get one row per person/blue. Also, use the current join syntax to join two tables.

Comment: Also, please edit your question and add the schema of both tables.

Comment: could you please post your mysql table structure with some data to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to `SUM` all the values of `Colour = 'Blue'` in `Favourite_Colour` for each person. Since MySQL treats a boolean expression as either 1 (true) or 0 (false) in a numeric context, this `SUM` will only be greater than 0 if a user has `Blue` as a favourite colour:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name, 
       CASE WHEN SUM(F.Colour = 'Blue') > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Fav_Blue
FROM People p
LEFT Join Favourite_Colour F ON F.person_ID = p.ID
GROUP BY p.ID, p.Name
```

You can also use an `EXISTS` expression to check for the existence of `Blue` for a person in the `Favourite_Colour` table:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.NAME,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Favourite_Colour F WHERE Colour = 'Blue' AND F.person_ID = p.ID) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Fav_Blue
FROM People p
```

Output (I took the liberty of assigning names to people 2 and 3):

```
ID  Name    Fav_Blue
1   Mark    Yes
2   Bill    No
3   Fred    Yes
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kBVC7cJuszdYw4NzJi6LeC/2)

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the case juts using a proper where

```
SELECT   "Yes" AS Fav_Blue, P.Name 
FROM People P
INNER JOIN Favourite_Colour FC ON P.ID = FC.person_ID 
WHERE FC.Colour = "Blue"
```

otherwise using you CASE  addin the case to the where

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN FC.Colour = "Blue" THEN  "Yes"
ELSE "No"
END AS Fav_Blue, P.Name
FROM People P
INNER JOIN Favourite_Colour FC ON P.ID = FC.person_ID 
WHERE CASE WHEN FC.Colour = "Blue" THEN  "Yes"
                ELSE "No"
               END = 'YES'
```

and for who have also others favorite colors

```
SELECT   "Yes" AS Fav_Blue, P.Name 
FROM People P
INNER JOIN Favourite_Colour FC ON P.ID = FC.FC.person_ID  
WHERE FC.Colour = "Blue"
INNER JOIN (
  select  person_ID 
  from  Favourite_Colour
  group by person_ID
  having count(*)>1
) t ON t.person_ID =  P.ID
```

Comment: This solved the problem for the person with ID 1, but what about the other people who don't have Blue as their favourite colour? They are not showing in the output at all with 'No'

Comment: @myxx   this is the answer  for what you asked ..   ..change the question after a valid answer is not fair  ...   "I only want to show the (Mark, Yes) row without the other one." .. is your question

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it with 2 more rows in the output to be more clear, although in the question I stated to return all the people's names

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT People.Name,
       (CASE when (Favourite_Colour.Color = "Blue") 
 THEN
      "Yes" 
 ELSE
      "No" 
 END) as Fav_Blue
FROM People LEFT JOIN Favourite_Colour 
ON People.id = Favourite_Colour.person_ID;
```